# 14.04 USB MP3 player not recognized as storage medium anymore

Tags: usb, mp3-player

After updating from 13.10 to 14.04 my MP3 player is not mounted anymore.
Under 13.10 it behaved like a normal USB stick and I could copy files to it.
Since the upgrade the device does not show up as block device anymore.

After a fresh reboot the stick gets mounted for a few seconds, and then disappears.

I can see the player with

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 020: ID 054c:0689 Sony Corp.
```

and

```
$ udevadm monitor
KERNEL[3031.177130] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.6 (usb)
KERNEL[3031.177631] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.6/2-1.6:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[3031.177769] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.6/2-1.6:1.0/host34 (scsi)
KERNEL[3031.177788] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.6/2-1.6:1.0/host34/scsi_host/host34 (scsi_host)
UDEV  [3031.190066] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.6 (usb)
UDEV  [3031.194110] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.6/2-1.6:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [3031.195647] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.6/2-1.6:1.0/host34 (scsi)
UDEV  [3031.196342] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.6/2-1.6:1.0/host34/scsi_host/host34 (scsi_host)
KERNEL[3031.199824] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.6/2-1.6:1.0/host34/scsi_host/host34 (scsi_host)
KERNEL[3031.199946] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.6/2-1.6:1.0/host34 (scsi)
UDEV  [3031.200736] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.6/2-1.6:1.0/host34/scsi_host/host34 (scsi_host)
UDEV  [3031.200761] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.6/2-1.6:1.0/host34 (scsi)
KERNEL[3031.368640] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.6/2-1.6:1.0/host35 (scsi)
KERNEL[3031.369862] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.6/2-1.6:1.0/host35/scsi_host/host35 (scsi_host)
UDEV  [3031.369877] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.6/2-1.6:1.0/host35 (scsi)
UDEV  [3031.369886] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.6/2-1.6:1.0/host35/scsi_host/host35 (scsi_host)
KERNEL[3031.536654] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.6/2-1.6:1.0/host35/scsi_host/host35 (scsi_host)
KERNEL[3031.536680] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.6/2-1.6:1.0/host35 (scsi)
UDEV  [3031.537269] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.6/2-1.6:1.0/host35/scsi_host/host35 (scsi_host)
UDEV  [3031.537293] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.6/2-1.6:1.0/host35 (scsi)
```

and

```
$ tail -f /var/log/syslog
Apr 28 20:32:51 ubuntu colord: Device added: sysfs-SONY-WALKMAN
Apr 28 20:32:51 ubuntu colord: Device added: sysfs-(null)
Apr 28 20:32:51 ubuntu kernel: [ 3219.231831] usb 2-1.6: usbfs: process 3053 (ThreadWeaver::T) did not claim interface 0 before use
Apr 28 20:32:51 ubuntu kernel: [ 3219.302565] usb 2-1.6: reset high-speed USB device number 24 using ehci-pci
Apr 28 20:32:51 ubuntu kernel: [ 3219.394921] usb-storage 2-1.6:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
Apr 28 20:32:51 ubuntu kernel: [ 3219.394966] scsi37 : usb-storage 2-1.6:1.0
Apr 28 20:32:51 ubuntu kernel: [ 3219.395038] usb 2-1.6: usbfs: process 3053 (ThreadWeaver::T) did not claim interface 0 before use
Apr 28 20:32:51 ubuntu kernel: [ 3219.470571] usb 2-1.6: reset high-speed USB device number 24 using ehci-pci
Apr 28 20:32:51 ubuntu kernel: [ 3219.563279] usb 2-1.6: usbfs: process 3053 (ThreadWeaver::T) did not claim interface 0 before use
Apr 28 20:32:51 ubuntu kernel: [ 3219.634589] usb 2-1.6: reset high-speed USB device number 24 using ehci-pci
Apr 28 20:32:51 ubuntu kernel: [ 3219.727049] usb-storage 2-1.6:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
Apr 28 20:32:51 ubuntu kernel: [ 3219.727152] scsi38 : usb-storage 2-1.6:1.0
Apr 28 20:32:51 ubuntu kernel: [ 3219.727532] usb 2-1.6: usbfs: process 3038 (ThreadWeaver::T) did not claim interface 0 before use
Apr 28 20:32:52 ubuntu kernel: [ 3219.802645] usb 2-1.6: reset high-speed USB device number 24 using ehci-pci
Apr 28 20:32:52 ubuntu kernel: [ 3219.895293] usb 2-1.6: usbfs: process 3053 (ThreadWeaver::T) did not claim interface 0 before use
```

But with `lsblk` the device does not show up at all.

Any hints how I can fix or debug this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay a bit more try and error and I found out that amarok was running in the background. When I quit amarok I could access the USB storage again.

Funny thing, but it took me a while to figure that out.

Comment: Disabling the MTP plugin in amarok solves my problems. Amarok is running and I can access the UBS storage on the player.